# Response status 201 not accepted in CORS requests

Tags: nginx, cors

I'm setting up an app with some REST webservices, that respond with 200 or 201 according to the result of the request.

On the other hand, i'm developing a javascript web application that has to use this webservices, so i'm dealing with CORS in the server-side with nginx adding the proper headers to the response.

The problem as i can tell, is that when the service responds with 201, cors headers don't reach the client. The first thought was that it was a problem/restriction on browsers, but then i realized that nginx was not adding the cors headers in any response with 201 status code.

The nginx config i'm using is available at https://github.com/UPCnet/maxserver/blob/master/production/nginx.conf

Any clue? Please ask if you need any other information/details

Thanks!

Comment: Already solved... nginx directive add_headers only work for a short list of status code, in which 201 it's not in.. Adding the headers_module and using it instead, allows to add custom headers to responses with 201 status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx directive add_headers only work for a short list of status code, in which 201 it's not in..

Adding the headers_module and using it instead, allows to add custom headers to responses with 201 status

Comment: Using it how? Nginx Config example please.